# Cassandra is not starting due to java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException when loading jar trigger

Tags: database, cassandra, nosql

I'm trying to use a Trigger in Cassandra 4.1, but initialization fails when loading the jar file

Trace:

```
cassandra_1  | INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,483 CustomClassLoader.java:83 - Loading new jar /etc/cassandra/triggers/cassandra-logger-0.2.jar
cassandra_1  | ERROR [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,488 JVMStabilityInspector.java:68 - Exception in thread Thread[OptionalTasks:1,5,OptionalTasks]
cassandra_1  | org.apache.cassandra.io.FSWriteError: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /tmp/lib/cassandra-0.jar
(...)
cassandra_1  | Caused by: java.nio.file.FileAlreadyExistsException: /tmp/lib/cassandra-0.jar
cassandra_1  |  at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixCopyFile.copy(Unknown Source)
cassandra_1  |  at java.base/sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.copy(Unknown Source)
cassandra_1  |  at java.base/java.nio.file.Files.copy(Unknown Source)
cassandra_1  |  at org.apache.cassandra.triggers.CustomClassLoader.addClassPath(CustomClassLoader.java:86)
cassandra_1  |  ... 22 common frames omitted
cassandra_1  | ERROR [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,493 DefaultFSErrorHandler.java:64 - Stopping transports as disk_failure_policy is stop
cassandra_1  | ERROR [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,494 StorageService.java:501 - Stopping native transport
cassandra_1  | INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,505 Server.java:176 - Stop listening for CQL clients
cassandra_1  | ERROR [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,506 StorageService.java:506 - Stopping gossiper
cassandra_1  | WARN  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,507 StorageService.java:405 - Stopping gossip by operator request
cassandra_1  | INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,507 Gossiper.java:2087 - Announcing shutdown
cassandra_1  | INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,509 StorageService.java:2950 - Node /192.168.96.2:7000 state jump to shutdown
cassandra_1  | INFO  [OptionalTasks:1] 2022-11-17 22:35:17,513 StorageService.java:2950 - Node /192.168.96.2:7000 state jump to shutdown
```

Jar file:
https://github.com/felipead/cassandra-logger/releases/download/v0.2/cassandra-logger-0.2.jar

docker-compose.yaml, and cassandra.yaml:
https://github.com/hofstede-matheus/MATB09-postgres-vs-cassandra

This error also happens with `hms-cassandra-triggers-1.0.1.jar`, so I think there is no problem with
`cassandra-logger-0.2.jar`

Tried with other .jar files and no success.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using `cassandra:3.0` image in the docker-compose.yaml solved this startup issue.

I think the triggers are not compatible with version 4.1 of Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

4.1.0 release of Apache Cassandra has changed the way to load the triggers jars using java.nio (java.nio.file.Files), in earlier releases ( 4.0 or 3.X ) uses Guava (com.google.common.io.Files).

Guava copy method, by default, overwrite a file if you have permissions but java.nio not.

To solve this problem it's as easy as modify the class org.apache.cassandra.triggers.CustomClassLoader on line 86 from:

```
 copy(inputJar.toPath(), out.toPath());
```

to:

```
 copy(inputJar.toPath(), out.toPath(),StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
```